# Split column string with delimiters into separate columns in azure kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a column 'Apples' in azure table that has this string: "Colour:red,Size:small".

Current situation:

```
|-----------------------|
| Apples                |
|-----------------------|
| Colour:red,Size:small |
|-----------------------|
```

Desired Situation:

```
|----------------|
| Colour | Size  |
|----------------|
| Red    | small |
|----------------|
```

Please help

Comment: So no matter how many properties there are, you still want to get a single record in the result? Doesn't look like a realistic example. Can you please explain what you really need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query gave me the desired results:
`| parse Apples with "Colour:" AppColour ", Size:" AppSize`

Remember to include all the different delimiters preceding each word you want to extract, e.g ", Size". Mind the space between.

This helped me then i used my intuition to customize the query according to my needs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator

Answer (score 14):

I'll answer the title as I noticed many people searched for a solution.

The key here is [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) operator (*expands multi-value dynamic arrays or property bags into multiple records*):

```
datatable (str:string)["aaa,bbb,ccc", "ddd,eee,fff"]
| project splitted=split(str, ',')
| mv-expand col1=splitted[0], col2=splitted[1], col3=splitted[2]
| project-away splitted
```

[project-away](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/projectawayoperator) operator allows us to *select what columns from the input exclude from the output*.

Result:

```
+--------------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+--------------------+
| aaa  | bbb  | ccc  |
| ddd  | eee  | fff  |
+--------------------+
```