# Get variable elements fron string / url using KQl

Tags: kql

I have various API calls (not written by me) which I want to analyse. The trouble is the bit of the URL that tells me is at the end of the URL

E.G:

> /API/XXX/1111/XXX/XX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/stringIwant/XXXX
> /API/XXXX/1111/XXXX/xxx55566/StringIwant
> /API/XXXX/111/XXX/XXX/XXX/xxx123/zzz/xx34/StringIwant

As you can see the string I want is at the end and of various lengths (and in some the 2nd to the end)

any idea on how to get it out?

Ive tried regex and even suffix which works as a filter (mostly) but not to extract the value

Comment: My work around code 

AzureDiagnostics   

|where originalHost_s contains "XXX"   
|where requestUri_s contains "API"  
|where requestUri_s contains "XXX"  
|where requestUri_s !contains "XXX"  
|parse kind =regex requestUri_s with * "/[A-Za-z]+/[A-Za-z]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/" var1:string  
|project Country = substring(var1,0,2),TimeGenerated,timeTaken_d  
|summarize avg(timeTaken_d),count()  by Country

Comment: can you please confirm, the value/substring from URL you are looking for constant (Like `StringIwant` is in current sample data) or it can be anything?

Comment: It can be any thing but will always be a string (e.g transaction, contract)

Comment: Got it. In 1st sample URL at the end, you have mentioned `XXXX` is that value constant or that can also be anything?

Comment: anything -sorry (well alpha)

Answer (score 0):

It is a smiged insane buuut

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where strlen(requestUri_s) >0
| project splitted=split(requestUri_s, '/'), requestUri_s
| mv-expand col1=splitted[0], col2=splitted[1], col3=splitted[2],col4=splitted[3],col5=splitted[4],col6=splitted[5],col7=splitted[6],col8=splitted[7],col9=splitted[8],col10=splitted[9],col11=splitted[10],col12=splitted[11],col13=splitted[12]
| project-away splitted
|where col2 =="API"
|extend a= case(strlen(col11)==0,col7,
                strlen(col12) ==0 or strlen(col12)>30,col11,
                     strlen(col13)==0,col12,
                    col13)
```

With thanks to [Split column string with delimiters into separate columns in azure kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63779632/split-column-string-with-delimiters-into-separate-columns-in-azure-kusto)

this does what I want